# Spring security 3.2 and CSRF injection in index.html file

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I am working on a web application using AJAX requests and static HTML/JS files. In order to prevent CSRF attack, I am thinking about adding CSRF token in index.html like this

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

However, since it is a static HTML file, I don't think Spring will inject the variable like it does for a JSP file.

Any ideas how could I instruct Spring to look at index.html and replace '${_csrf.token}' var with actual token value?

Comment: Are you using JSPs? Do you have view resolver set up?

Comment: No JSP at all. Plain .html files.

Comment: Then it is not possible ;). Maybe with SiteMesh or Thymeleaf... but still you would need some sort of templating engine.

Comment: Btw. how do you pass model entities to your views? Are you using plain HTML with JS and REST view Spring?

Comment: Initially, I am loading HTML/JS as static files. Then i have REST end-points configured to fetch model in json format using AJAX calls. Once I have data in client side, I use jQuery to render it into html .

Comment: Then you can send the CSRF token with the REST response.

Comment: How do you get the CSRF token this way? I haven't been able to find a way to generate a new one programmatically apart from the ${_csrf.token} syntax. @PavelHoral

Comment: Just let Spring inject `CsrfToken` into your controller... (I am guessing based on [CsrfTokenArgumentResolver](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/method/annotation/CsrfTokenArgumentResolver.java)).